# CSS dashed stroke hover

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a smooth transition when hovering over a selection. However, I added some text that has a stroke that is dashed. I am trying to include a smooth hover effect onto the text when a mouse hovers over it. For the life of me I cannot figure this out.

Please go to the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/YLCPapi/pen/yLGYJXG) for more examples

```css
#box3 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f2ece2;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

#box3:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 black;
  background-color: #ede2ce;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dashedText {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease;
}

#dashedText:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id='box3' class='btn-1'>
  <h1>
    <svg width="400" height="100">
    <text id='dashedText' x="10" y="50" font-size="36" font-weight="bold" fill="none" stroke="black"  
    stroke-dasharray="4,2">
      Hello There
    </text>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I see a hover effect in the CodePen because of the JavaScript that you did not include in your question. Please explain how the current result differs from your desired result.

Comment: Wow---Thank you! I thought I could use JS to make the change, didn't work either. From here the idea was also to remove the dashed once the text is filled. I should be able to accomplish this from here. Can't believe this site actually works---this is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using classes instead of id attributes/selectors.

In fact IDs should be unique.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2ece2;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ht1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f2ece2;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s, color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 black;
  background-color: #ede2ce;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.dashedText {
  stroke-dashoffset: 20;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease, fill 0.3s 0.3s ease;
}

.box:hover .dashedText {
  fill: black;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.box4{
border:2px dotted green
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#box4">Jump to box 3</a> | <a href="#box4">Jump to box 4</a></p> 
<div id='first-data' class='ht1'></div>
<div class='row'>
  <div id="box2" class='box btn-1'>
    <h1>
      <svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <text class='dashedText h1' x="50%" y="50" text-anchor="middle"  font-weight="bold" fill="transparent" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="4,2">
      Hello There
    </text>
    </svg>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div id="box2" class='box'>
    <h2 class="h1">Hello there</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="box3" class='box'>
    <h2 class="h1">Hello there</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="box4" class='box box4'>
    <h2 class="h1">Hello there</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above example applies the `box` class to every card div.
As all boxes share the same border, fill and hover styles we don't need Ids.
However you could assign unique Ids to each box e.g to attach specific events  to each item or an anchor target.

The `<text>` stroke and fill transition can be achieved with CSS alone:

```
.dashedText {
  stroke-dashoffset: 20;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease, fill 0.3s 0.3s ease;
}

.box:hover .dashedText {
  fill: black;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

#### Further reading

- [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)
- [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Thank you for providing the links----as u can tell, I'm new to programming and every single step is an uphill battle....but I'm here for it all----thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In SVG, the color property doesn't directly control the color of the text. In your case, you are working with an SVG text element, and that's why changing the color property did not have an effect. You need to use fill property to change the text color on hover.

```
#dashedText:hover {
    fill: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed to added javaScript code. Example that you have provided thare is used HTML, CSS for this box hover effect and Javascript for text hover effect may be you have not added javascript. Check below for working example.

Hi, I think you have missed to added javaScript code. Example that you have provided thare is used HTML, CSS for this box hover effect and Javascript for text hover effect may be you have not added javascript. Check below for working example.

```js
const dashedText = document.getElementById("dashedText");

dashedText.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
 dashedText.style.strokeDashoffset = "0";
});

dashedText.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
 dashedText.style.strokeDashoffset = "20";
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2ece2;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#box {
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: wheat;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

#box:hover {
  box-shadow: -10px 8px 0px black;
  background-color: wheat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#box3 {
  margin-top: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f2ece2;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  transition: background-color 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s, border 0.3s,
    color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

#box3:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 black;
  background-color: #ede2ce;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#dashedText {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.3s ease;
}

#dashedText:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <div id="box3" class="btn-1">
    <h1>
      <svg width="400" height="100">
        <text
          id="dashedText"
          x="10"
          y="50"
          font-size="36"
          font-weight="bold"
          fill="none"
          stroke="black"
          stroke-dasharray="4,2"
        >
          Hello There
        </text>
      </svg>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you just copy and paste their CodePen as your answer?

Comment: Not just a Copy, Actually you don't know PapiCLY is new here so make this platform  friendly for him. This is not just a copy paste. I have checked problem and try to make batter example and I have also write in deep what's his mistake and how he can improve that. and I have done what you have not done.

Comment: I was attempting to use JS to solve the problem---but it didnt work thats why I didnt include that in my explanation----that you for the assist...I am definetly new here and to programming. trying to improve every day

Comment: @VivekTarsariya What you have not done is explain what changes you made to the code, which would be very helpful. We shouldn't have to inspect every line to look for differences. The hover effect in the snippet appears identical to the CodePen.